Spressense CO2センサーとELTRESアドオンボードの併用でHard Fault
今MH-Z19BというCO2センサーとELTRESアドオンボードをSpressenseで使用して
測定したCO2情報とGNSS情報をクラウドに送信するコードを作成しようとしているのですが、何度やってもHard Faultになります。
コードを確認してみて頂いて修正箇所などあればお教えください。
私が書いたコードです-CO2ELTRES

Eltres単体であれば動作するのか、CO2センサー単体であれば動作するのか、setup()の実行だけでエラーが出るのか、Hard Faultはコーディングエラーの可能性が高いので、どこが動作するとエラーになるのか、もう少し切り分けてみた方が良いと思います
